# Deploy Multiple Projects in a Single Solution for VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm new in VSTS and I'm in this case, I have a single solution built on Visual Studio 2015. It contains 7 or 8 projects that reference each others, I need only to build and release 3 project of them on Azure VM via Visual Studio Team Services so the question is what is the best approach to do this?

Clarification: the projects that I want to deploy are 2 aspnet web sites and a windows communication foundation library.

In my iis I have the following configuration:

Mysite (the root site with the following applications inside)

- RPT (other web site)
- WCF (wcf library)

This is my current VSTS build definition and with the following artifacts:

[image]

But I can only select one zip to deploy:

[image]

I do not know if this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deploy the three projects to Azure VM, you need to **add different tasks in your release pipeline to deploy the three projects separately**.

For now, you are using an IIS Web App Deploy task you deploy one project. Then you can add other task to deploy other two projects separately.